# MVC 5 (IdentityUser) and 3-tier architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, 3-tier

I have a question about 3-tier architecture: what should I do with `IdentityUser` in **MVC 5**  context? I'll create **DAL**, **BL**, **UI** (MVC). Should I implement user part (registration, authorization, authentication, roles) on the **UI**? Or it should be another assembly (another **MVC** project)? May anybody give me any advances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in MVC you implement your permissions with `IAuthorizationFilter` interface.

So you can easily create **ACL** (Access Control List) project as *class library* type project, add refference to your **UI** project and use there this class as attribute (or filter in MVC context) on all `Controller` methods that you need.

Comment: Thanks! As I understand, it's necessary to create assembly in which I will implement  registration, authorization, authentication, roles logic. Am I right?

Comment: it's up to you - use separate assembly or implement it as part of MVC project.

Comment: but if you create it as separate library it can help you if you somewhere in future you need to inplement row security (in your BL layer) i think.

Comment: So, I need DAL, BL, UI + ACL. I'll do it. Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander Would you be able to share sample of your project as I'm also looking for the same issue.